# Is it possible to evaluate shell commands (to be executed on the host) inside a docker env_file?

Tags: shell, docker, environment

I run a docker container with `docker run --env-file envfile image`. `envfile` contains environment variables like `LISTEN=localhost:12345`, `SSH_USER=jannis`, etc.

I tried adding a variable as follows: `` SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa` ``. I expected Docker to execute the command in `$()` *on the host machine* and set the variable to its output; however, Docker just set the variable literally. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

While writing this, I figured I can just let the executing shell do the work for me and pass `` --env SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa` ``.